# Color Balance with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

How to do color balance with OpenCV. I have an image with a white paper in it, how can I balance the whole image color based on that white paper. Is there any code has implemented in Python?

I've tried this method

> Get the rgb mean value of the "white" background. Then compute the ratios of 255/r, 255/g, 255/b using the r,g,b values from the "white" rgb color. Then multiply the red, green and blue channels by those ratios.

But there is a problem I encounter:
I have to `imwrite` the balanced image and `imshow` it again to display the right result. If I only `imshow` it directly (with converting the datatype to `np.uint8`), the shown image is strange and not right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own, and (2) learn how to ask questions. Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem. What have you tried so far? Please show some of your attempts/codes.

Comment: Get the rgb color of your "white" background. Then compute the ratios of 255/r, 255/g, 255/b using the r,g,b values from the "white" rgb color. Then multiply the red, green and blue channels by those ratios.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/DavidYKay/9dad6c4ab0d8d7dbf3dc.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks! I've edited my question, and the method you provided is what I'm using, but there is some problem with it.

Comment: Post your code. Read the help section about posting verifiable code so that it can be tested. You probably need to clip the output image to the range 0 to 255. See clip()